# How do we get the types returned by array.map to be used as React components in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use typescript in React, How do I use it directly as a component of react when I use Array.map to return HTML elements?
Since Array.map returns React.ReactElement[],I can't use it directly as the react component.
What am I supposed to do?

```
const EquipmentMenu: React.ReactElement[] = () => {
  return [1, 2, 3].map(item => <span>{item}</span>)
}

const A: React.FC = () => {
  return <EquipmentMenu />
}
```

online example: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-euler-38vft

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your example? Seems to compile/run fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use React.Fragment

```
<React.Fragment>
  [1, 2, 3].map(item => <span>{item}</span>)
</React.Fragment>
```